# websphere liberty - Force https for site without user authentication

Tags: java, ssl, websphere-liberty

I want to configure websphere liberty profile to serve pages over https only. In particular, requests to http should either be blocked, or redirected to https.

I have set up `<security-constraint>` in web.xml as follows:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>UserConstraint</display-name>

    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>UserCollection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>HEAD</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I have also added `[ssl-1.0]` feature and a default key store. This causes HTTPS to work correctly, however all pages are still accessible over HTTP (it does not redirect or block).

Next I added the feature `[appSecurity-2.0]`, and this causes HTTP to redirect to HTTPS correctly. However, I see the following error in the console:

```
[ERROR   ] CWWKS3005E: A configuration exception has occurred. No UserRegistry implementation service is available.  Ensure that you have a user registry configured.
```

As mentioned, I do not have a user registry set up in server.xml, as the authentication is done in the application itself. What should be done to resolve this error, without changing the application to use User Registry?

Also, is there any other configuration needed in web.xml, to prevent access over HTTP? I would have thought that the `<security-constraint>` was enough for that?

EDIT: I am sending a Basic Auth header for doing the authentication, in case it was unclear.

Comment: Just add `<basicRegistry></basicRegistry>` to your `server.xml`. It will not be used by your application since your `security-constraint` doesn't define any `auth-constraint`.

Comment: This does give me the following message (not an error so that is better) : `[AUDIT   ] CWWKS1100A: Authentication did not succeed for user ID user. An invalid user ID or password was specified.` (I also tried setting the realm to be different from the one used by the application). Again, the application otherwise works correctly, but would this be a problem?

Comment: @Gas You could add your comment as an answer (and hopefully also answer my previous comment, if possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<basicRegistry></basicRegistry>` to your `server.xml`. It will not be used by your application since your `security-constraint` doesn't define any `auth-constraint`.

Regarding your other comment:
This might be a result of server trying to interpret your basic auth header and not finding user in the registry.

However, if you are using basic authentication anyway, you could benefit from allowing server to create that request by protecting your web module and instead of using Basic registry, implement your custom registry as Liberty feature see [Developing a custom user registry for the Liberty profile](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_sec_custmr.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-4-10-5&lang=en)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest thing to do is to disable the http port in the server.xml:

`<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint" httpPort="-1"/>`

Comment: I think it will not support automatic redirection to https, but will just respond with the "unable to connect" message.

Comment: That is true, but it was one of the options in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your web.xml add:

```
<user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
</user-data-constraint>
```

That will redirect to https.